# Extracting specific group value from a data.table list and returning as a vector in R

Tags: r, filter, data.table, apply, sapply

I have a list of some data, Its looks like:

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(age_group = c("young", "old"), ratio = runif(2))
dt2 <- data.table(age_group = c("young", "old"), ratio = runif(2))

dt_list <- list(
    list(ratio_by_group = dt1),
    list(ratio_by_group = dt2),
    list(ratio_by_group = NA)
)
```

```
dt_list
[[1]]
[[1]]$ratio_by_group
   age_group     ratio
1:     young 0.5956572
2:       old 0.5053023


[[2]]
[[2]]$ratio_by_group
   age_group     ratio
1:     young 0.4632962
2:       old 0.2356656


[[3]]
[[3]]$ratio_by_group
[1] NA
```

I want tp exact the ratio information for a specific group (i.e., 'young') and return it as a vector. I used the following code:

```
sapply(dt_list, function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x$ratio_by_group), x$ratio_by_group[age_group=='young', ratio], NA))
```

```
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.5956572 0.4632962
[2,] 0.5956572 0.4632962
[3,] 0.5956572 0.4632962
[4,] 0.5956572 0.4632962
```

My expected output is

```
[1] "0.5956572" "0.4632962" NA
```

Comment: `x$ratio_by_group` is an entire data.table, which you are then checking if any value is missing in the `ifelse`. Which will return 4 values (2 for `age_group`, 2 for `ratio`) in a matrix. I'm not sure how to suggest to fix this though, because I'm not sure what you are testing for with that `is.na` check.

Comment: Hi @thelatemail, In my real data, this `data.table` list is a part of return by another function, some of  `ratio_by_group` is missing because missing data and return some NA (eg, samples can't pass filter params), I want to keep this

Comment: But you're returning only the 'young' subset of the values in the `ratio` column - do you just want to check those particular 'young' rows in `ratio` to see if they're NA or not?

Comment: Because if `x$ratio_by_group` is `NA` (not `data.table`) `x$ratio_by_group[age_group=='young', ratio]` will not work

Comment: @thelatemail I think I understand the problem you pointed out, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Recursion:

```
fn <- function(x){
    if(is.data.table(x)) x[age_group == 'young', ratio]
    else if(is.list(x[[1]])) unlist(lapply(x, fn),use.names = FALSE)
}

fn(dt_list)
[1] 0.6224014 0.8436315
```

Comment: Hi, @Onyambu, Its work, I also add a esle brunch to return `NA` because I update a typo in question,  thank you. Could you please tell me why the previous code doesn't work?

Comment: @zhang the issue with your code was tackled in the comments

Answer (score 1):

You could case-handle the `NA`s and subset the rest to your requirements.

```
> sapply(dt_list, \(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NA else unname(unlist(el(x)[age_group == 'young', 'ratio'])))
[1] 0.4314703 0.1398862        NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dt_list)
list(list(ratio_by_group = structure(list(age_group = c("young", 
"old"), ratio = c(0.431470313109457, 0.41186331724748)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x561d15f42ac0>, index = structure(integer(0), "`__age_group`" = 2:1))), 
    list(ratio_by_group = structure(list(age_group = c("young", 
    "old"), ratio = c(0.139886221848428, 0.171009620418772)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x561d15f42ac0>, index = structure(integer(0), "`__age_group`" = 2:1))), 
    list(ratio_by_group = NA))
```